# Saving videos with meshcat?

Tags: drake

What is the standard way of saving videos using MeshcatVisualizer? I know the following works for wrappers of PyPlotVisualizer:

```
visualizer.start_recording()
simulator.AdvanceTo(T)
ani = visualizer.get_recording_as_animation()
```

But the two relevant methods are not available for MeshcatVisualizer, and there don't seem to be any examples in the repo that create videos using it, and none of the methods that the class does have seemed like promising candidates. Failing that, is there another way of saving videos for 3D visualizations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meshcat has an animation tool: https://github.com/rdeits/meshcat-python/blob/master/animation_demo.ipynb , you can access `MeshcatVisualizer`'s `meshcat.Visualizer` instance via `MeshcatVisualizer.vis`. However, `MeshcatVisualizer` doesn't have a function like `MeshcatVisualizer.convert_to_video` that supports this animation tool at the moment. Perhaps the easier route for now is screen recording.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I had seen the meshcat animation demo, but a couple of things weren't clear about a Drake workflow: 1) how to "feed" the scene_graph output into the meshcat Animation object (as it's filled up by hand in the example), 2) in the example, the Animation .rar output is converted to video with ffmpeg, which would be fine for me, but I couldn't figure out how to make Animation save a .rar in the first place.

Comment: This is correct--meshcat itself has a built-in animation tool, and the meshcat browser UI has a "record" button to capture each frame of an animation and download it as a `.tar` file, which can then be converted with the `meshcat.animation.convert_frames_to_video` function in Python. Currently, however, the Drake `MeshcatVisualizer` does not use that animation API, so meshcat can't capture or record the animation. I would suggest using a screen-grabber tool like GTKRecordMyDesktop if you want to record something from Drake.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you.

Comment: The output of `SceneGraph` is a "pose bundle" which includes the pose of every object in the MultibodyPlant. The interaction between pose bundle and meshcat happens [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/fb0ce7750f56c859873d1f0eb095a019e8eae961/bindings/pydrake/systems/meshcat_visualizer.py#L372-L374), where the pose of each object is read out from pose bundle and set in meshcat. I would start by doing something similar with the Animation API.

Comment: Update: `MeshcatVisualizer` now supports saving simulations as animations, as shown [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/e7ef9a96927229c591c605549594fbb07a3d1efd/bindings/pydrake/systems/test/meshcat_visualizer_test.py#L98-L100). 

This can be saved as an html file, as shown [here](https://github.com/rdeits/meshcat-python/blob/e25b1e61029990df7c4ca433471ffbe70ce241cd/src/meshcat/tests/test_drawing.py#L236-L240).

Answer (score 1):

I don't *believe* that meshcat offers it's own recording functionality, which means the recommended workflow would be to just use your favorite screen recorder software.  I've forwarded this to a few meshcat experts in case they have something better to recommend.

Update: In addition to rdeits answer above, he had a few more details in email:

> there's a built in animation API with recording support in
>   `meshcat-python` (see "Recording an Animation" in
>   https://github.com/rdeits/meshcat-python/blob/master/animation_demo.ipynb
>   ), but AFAICT Drake's MeshcatVisualizer isn't hooked up to it. It
>   might not be that hard to do so--the basic idea is that you can use
>   `at_frame` to get a representation of a single frame of an animation
>   that behaves like a `meshcat.Visualizer`. You can call `set_transform`
>   on that frame, and rather than moving anything in the viewer it will
>   instead record that action into an animation track. Then you can send
>   the whole animation at once to the visualizer and let the browser side
>   handle replaying and recording it.

Comment: Along these lines, this is probably related? https://github.com/rdeits/meshcat-python/issues/16, relevant source code: https://github.com/rdeits/meshcat-python/blob/ceb8bd68e3f4711b30001876efc5b49530038866/src/meshcat/animation.py#L132. EDIT: See Robin's answer above.